# Using theano.scan within PyMC3 gives TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: theano, pymc3, theano.scan

I would like to to use theano.scan within pymc3. I run into problems when I add more than two variables as `sequences`. Here is a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

a = np.ones(5)
b = np.ones(5)

basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:
    a_plus_b, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda a, b: a + b, sequences=[a, b])
```

results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "StackOverflowExample.py", line 23, in <module>
sequences=[a, b])
File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan.py", line 586, in scan
scan_seqs = [seq[:actual_n_steps] for seq in scan_seqs]
File "\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\scan_module\scan.py", line 586, in <listcomp>
scan_seqs = [seq[:actual_n_steps] for seq in scan_seqs]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

However, when I run the same theano.scan outside a pymc model block, everything works fine:

```
a = T.vector('a')
b = T.vector('b')
a_plus_b, update = theano.scan(fn=lambda a, b: a + b, sequences=[a, b])
a_plus_b_function = theano.function(inputs=[a, b], outputs=a_plus_b, updates=update)

a = np.ones(5)
b = np.ones(5)
print(a_plus_b_function(a, b))
```

prints `[2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]`, like it should.

In addition, the problem seems to be specific to adding more than one `sequences`. Everything works just fine when there is one variable in `sequences` and one in `non-sequences`. The following code works:

```
a = np.ones(5)
c = 2

basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:

    a_plus_c, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda a, c: a + c, sequences=[a], non_sequences=[c])
    a_plus_c_print = T.printing.Print('a_plus_c')(a_plus_c)
```

prints `a_plus_c __str__ = [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]`, as expected.

**Note**: I can't just use a + b instead of theano.scan because my actual function is more complex. I actually want to have something like this:

```
rewards = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])  # reward (1) or no reward (0)
choices = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0])  # action left (1) or right (0)
Q_old = 0  # initial Q-value
alpha = 0.1  # learning rate

def update_Q(reward, choice, Q_old, alpha):
    return Q_old + choice * alpha * (reward - Q_old)

Q_left, _ = theano.scan(fn=update_Q,
                        sequences=[rewards, choices],
                        outputs_info=[Q_old],
                        non_sequences=[alpha])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple mistake! Everything is working as soon as I define `a` and `b` as tensor variables. Adding those two lines did the job:

```
a = T.as_tensor_variable(np.ones(5))
b = T.as_tensor_variable(np.ones(5))
```